# Symfony EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I try to get from my Form EntityType, which will get from the entity the name and the ID.

```
->add('supplier', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => \App\Entity\Supplier::class,
    'choice_value' => 'id',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
])
```

I'm getting results as expected.

```
<select id="expense_supplier" name="expense[supplier]" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">PayPal</option>
    <option value="2">FB</option>
    <option value="3">Yotube</option>
</select>
```

And he's getting the Value AS integer, as the entity requirement,

but when I submit the form, I'm getting the error:

> Expected argument of type "integer", "App\Entity\Supplier" given.

My Supplier Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Supplier
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $tax_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=25)
     */
    private $category;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTaxId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tax_id;
    }

    public function setTaxId(string $tax_id): self
    {
        $this->tax_id = $tax_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?int
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(int $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/expense/add", name="expense_add")
 */
public function add(Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(\App\Form\ExpenseType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('expense_list');
    }
    return $this->render('Admin/SuppliersTemplate.html.twig', [
        'display' => 'form',
        'title' => 'add.expense',
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

I try a lot of ways, but nothing helps,

Using Symfony 4.1

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your entity class file?

Comment: yes, i update the post.

Comment: So somewhere in your code you are trying to validate that supplier is an integer?  When you use an EntityType you actually end up with a Supplier object.  The type class takes care of converting the form value to an actual object.  Maybe show where the error is coming from.

Comment: Share the controller method in which this form is getting submitted

Comment: 1. when i change this Type to IntType it's working, and i need it as Select Option, and the form submit without any issue

Comment: i also update the code with conroller

Comment: can you also show your Expense Entity?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't specify the relation to the supplier property.

in  `Expense` Entity property supplier change to this

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier")
 * @JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $supplier;
```

don't forget to update the schema

---

If that doesn't work then share your Expense entity